# Cocoa Touch - Segmented Controls

Tags: cocoa-touch

How can I get whats been selected in a segmented control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `selectedSegmentIndex`.

EDIT:
To retrieve the title of the segment, pass this `NSInteger` into `titleForSegmentAtIndex:`. Please note that if `selectedSegmentIndex` does not return a positive value, using it for `titleForSegmentAtIndex` will cause an error.